# how to change an element of a list in pyspark df?

Tags: pyspark

suppose I have a list of items. I wanna change `A`,'C','F','H' and 'G' by `B` in all rows.

```
col1
['A','C','F','H4','G1'] 
['A1','C2','F','H2','G'] 
['A2','C1','F1','H','G'] 
['A3','C','F5','H1','G'] 
['A1','C3','F','H0','G'] 
['A','C','F3','H7','G6']
```

output:

```
col1
['B','B','B','H4','G1'] 
['A1','C2','B','H2','B'] 
['A2','C1','F1','B','B'] 
['A3','B','F5','H1','B'] 
['A1','C3','B','H0','B'] 
['B','B','F3','H7','G6']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) with regex:

```
import re
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType


map_func = lambda arr: [re.sub(r"^[A,C,F,H,G]$", 'B', x) for x in arr]
array_udf = f.udf(map_func, ArrayType(StringType()))

data = [
        [['A', 'C', 'F', 'H4', 'G1']],
        [['A1', 'C2', 'F', 'H2', 'G']],
        [['A2', 'C1', 'F1', 'H', 'G']]
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['col1'])
df.select(array_udf(df.col1).name("result")).show(10, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Spark 3.1+**

You can use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html).

```py
df.select(
    F.transform('col1', lambda x: F.regexp_replace(x, '^(A|C|F|H|G)$', 'B'))
    .alias('col1'))
```